# Data.Table fwrite slowing down for list of writes

Tags: r, data.table

I couldn't find this asked anywhere else before.

I currently have a few use cases where I want to write a list of dataframes to a csv each. The lists are usually between 200-1500 elements in length. What I am finding is that after a few files are written, the write process slows a lot.

My currently implementation is:

```
lapply(write_set, 
       function(x) 
         fwrite(x, 
                paste0("Directory/", x$dataset_id[1], ".csv")))
```

where each element of the list is a ~200 rows by 40 columns dataframe. The output files are also relatively small at ~40-50KB. Its currently taking ~20 mins to write 1400 such files.

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: What is `dataset_id`?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question to answer this. Its the first value on the dataset_id column of each dataframe.

Comment: With datafames that small it is worth trying `readr::write_csv()` as well. The difference may be marginal but it is worth a shot.